# video doesn't play in full screen mode in android

Tags: android, video-processing, video-player

I am learning android first time so i started the application of video player.i have written code correctly but i don,t know whats going wrong.

The problem is that i hide navigation bar but the shadow of navigation bar is displaying there and back button from navigation bar is not working.And Some Video is not play in full screen. it play only in half of screen

Here is my code

```
public class VideoList extends AppCompatActivity {
File root;
private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
ListView videolist;
String[] list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String dir = extras.getString("Dir");
    root = new File(dir);
    list = new String[3];
    File listFile[] = root.listFiles();
    videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.videolist);
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mp4")
                    || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".avi")
                    || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mpeg")
                    || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".3gp") || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mkv")) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                String filePath = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                File file = new File(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
    list = new String[fileList.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < fileList.size(); j++) {

        String temp = fileList.get(j).getAbsolutePath();
        list[j] = temp;
        Log.v("bbb", j + " " + list[j]);
    }
    Ticket_adapter adapter = new Ticket_adapter(VideoList.this, list);
    videolist.setAdapter(adapter);
    videolist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent ii = new Intent(VideoList.this, ViewVideo.class);
            ii.putExtra("Fullpath", fileList.get(position).getAbsolutePath());
            startActivity(ii);
        }
    });
}

}


class Ticket_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
String[] list;
Bitmap bMap;
String aaaaa;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public Ticket_adapter(VideoList context, String[] list) {
    super(context, R.id.list_item, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;


}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        Log.v("Aa", "" + list[position]);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    }
    TextView idtxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gool);
    TextView dur = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);
    ImageView videol = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.abcd);
    File abc = new File(list[position]);

    idtxt.setText(abc.getName());
    Bitmap bMap;
    bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(list[position], MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    try {
        videol.setImageBitmap(bMap);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("DDD", " " + list[position]);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(list[position]));
    int duration = mp.getDuration();
    mp.release();
/*convert millis to appropriate time*/
    if (TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toHours(duration) == 0) {
        aaaaa = String.format("%d:%d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) -
                                 TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)));
    } else {
        aaaaa = String.format("%d:%d:%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration) % 60,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)));
    }
    Log.v("ads", "" + aaaaa);

    dur.setText(aaaaa);

    return convertView;

}
 }
```

Here i attaching screenshot of my videoplayer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br9dr.png)
Here at bottom side and at navigation bar shadow is displaying.i want to remove that shodaow .and back button from navigation bar is not working
And My ViewVideo.java

```
public class ViewVideo extends AppCompatActivity {
String dir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_video);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    dir = extras.getString("Fullpath");
    File aa = new File(dir);
    Log.v("AAAA", dir);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    try {
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(dir);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

Here at bottom side and at navigation bar shadow is displaying.i want to remove that shadow .and back button from navigation bar is not working.
Please solve my problem i am got getting solution from last week.

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats your require screen ?

Comment: i cant understand what you want to say

Comment: i get  grat border/shadow at bottom line and at navigation bar

Comment: As you have attached your current output screen but i am asking about your require output screen .

Comment: i taken screenshot from my moto g3.i want play video in full screen in every device

Comment: change yheme of your activity to fullscreen

Comment: how to change theme'

Comment: from manifest file in your particular video play activity theme

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"   or   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);